# In a reference node with only a list of ids, do we only have to use 'true' as the value?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm planning data structure like this for an food/potluck event where people can bring or reserve food.

```
{
    "potLuckEvents": {
        "eventID1": {
            "cake": {
                "userID1" : 2
                "userID2" : 3
             }
            "burger": {
                "userID3" : 1
                "userID4" : 2
             }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example, userID1 will be bringing 2 servings of cake to the event. All examples I have seen in the documentation were using something like:

```
"userID1" : true
```

I'm wondering if there is a specific reason for the list of ids to only have `true` as the value? Can I use non-true value for this case?

==========

**Extra:**

I'm also thinking to do use the int value for status of event invitation

```
{
    "potLuckEvents": {
        "eventID1": {
            "attendees": {
                "userID1" : -1
                "userID2" : 0
                "userID3" : 1
             }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example:

- userID1 declined invitation
- userID2 did not accept or decline
- invitation yet userID3 accepted invitation

Is this another good use case to use int values instead of 'true'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a node can be any valid [JSON value type](http://www.json.org/).

The reason you see `true` (more often than other values) is because when you're [creating an index node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) (essentially a list of "foreign keys") there isn't any real value to store. But since a node without a value will be deleted immediately, it's a convention to use `true` as the value.